# Recreating Apple's Drop down "browse all built-in Apps" button

Tags: javascript

Anyone knows what apple uses to achieve this effect I found on their iPhone page ?  Is that pure css (i doubt it), custom javascript or they are using prototype/scriptaculous framework ?  How can I achieve this effect for myself ? 
Here is the link to try for yourself http://www.apple.com/iphone/built-in-apps/

Stage 1:
From this...
[image: buil-in apps button retracted![][1]]
To that ! Clicking the "Browse all built-in Apps button will only make the menu collapse, back to stage 1
[image: buil-in apps button expanded]
credits go to apple.com

Answer (score 4):

You can do this trivially in jQuery:

```
$('link selector').click(function() { $('other selector').slideToggle(); });
```

Comment: No; you are not correct.  You should learn Javascript and jQuery.

Comment: k, i'll se how that works out, hopefully i may tag your answer right. Thanks

Comment: Bit pitiful to remove your comment when you're put in place. Anyways. Answer above, is the way to go in my opinion as well.